# Selecting rows with the highest priority

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a query, and I'm a bit stuck.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    routine_actions AS ra
JOIN 
    routines AS r ON r.id = ra.routine_id
JOIN 
    account_routines AS ar ON ar.routine_id = r.id
JOIN 
    accounts AS a ON a.id = ar.account_id
WHERE
    (ra.last_run + INTERVAL ra.interval_minutes MINUTE <= NOW() OR ra.last_run IS NULL)
AND
    r.created_at + INTERVAL r.runtime_days DAY > NOW()
```

What I'm trying to do:

An `account` has many routines. Only one `routine` can be used at a time, and that's the `routine` with the highest priority. The table that contains the priority column is `account_routines` because accounts can reuse routines and specify a different priority.

A higher number equals a higher priority. Currently the query is pulling all routines from all accounts. But I only need one routine with the highest priority from each account.

How is this possible? I don't need the solution, just where to look so I can figure out how to solve this problem.

Comment: have you tried `ORDER BY ar.priority desc`??

Comment: `ORDER BY` would still include the lower priority routines right? I am working with multiple accounts, and I only need 1 routine per account. If I user `ORDER BY` that's going to give a very mixed result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to locate the max(priority) and include that in the joins to limit the rows returned. e.g.

```
SELECT
      *
FROM routine_actions AS ra
      JOIN routines AS r ON r.id = ra.routine_id
      JOIN account_routines AS ar ON ar.routine_id = r.id
      JOIN (
            SELECT
                  account_id
                , MAX(priority) AS max_priority
            FROM account_routines
            GROUP BY
                  account_id
      ) AS mxr ON ar.priority = mxr.max_priority
                  AND ar.account_id = mxr.account_id
      JOIN accounts AS a ON a.id = ar.account_id
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Spot on, this worked. Originally I tried to follow this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html ... but wasn't having any luck. Many thanks for the solution.

Comment: I've just realized a problem. What if account contains 2 routines. One with priority of 4, other with 10. If the routine with priority of 10 is inactive, the 4 will never be returned? I was thinking of adding a WHERE clause to the SELECT within the JOIN, but I'd need a JOIN within a JOIN to pull the required table in. I think things could get messy, or have performance issue that way?

Comment: looks fine, I woud just adjust the where clause so you don't alter data to suit compaison to now(), do it the other way around, alter now to suit the data: `WHERE r.created_at >  ( NOW() - INTERVAL r.runtime_days DAY )`